# wpa_supplicant unexpectedly running on server

Tags: centos, wpa-supplicant

I discovered that wpa_supplicant is running on some of my CentOS 6.4 servers, without having been explicitly declared in the chkconfig setup. What can be causing this ?

```
$ chkconfig --list | grep wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
$ pgrep -l wpa
1767 wpa_supplicant
```

Answer (score 0):

[NetworkManager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) will run it.

See [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-NetworkManager.html). It **may** be installed by default, or can be pulled in as a dependency if you installed a desktop (Gnome, KDE, etc.)